# page can not be correctly rendered while the router changed

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, express

New to Express/node, and just built a simple code.

I test the url "localhost:3000/detail", and it works fine. However, I test the url "localhost:3000/detail/test1", the page did not show correctly.

The second function "/"  render the page correctly while the "/test1" did not, I have checked the directory of css; could not figure it out.

detail.controller.js

```
//page are not correct 
router.get('/test1', function (req, res) {  
  res.render('detail');
});

//page correctly shown with css style
router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('detail');
});
```

server.js

```
app.use('/detail', require('./controller/detail.controller'));
app.use("/css-detail",  express.static(__dirname + '/app/detail/css'));
app.use("/js-detail", express.static(__dirname + '/app/detail/js'));
app.use("/img-detail",  express.static(__dirname + '/app/detail/img'));
app.use("/fonts",  express.static(__dirname + '/app/detail/fonts'));
```

detail.ejs (partial)

```
<head>
...
<!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-detail/bootstrap.min.css">

    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-detail/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-detail/owl.carousel.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-detail/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css-detail/responsive.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Please elaborate upon "the page did not show correctl"

Comment: not correct means css files were not be loaded for the ejs, and the ejs has no style .

Answer (score 0):

Changed the code a little bit, and just added '*' before 'css-detail, now it works. ..

```
app.use("/*css-detail",  express.static(__dirname + '/app/detail/css'));
```